# Will a nest work for my hvac system

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I have a heat pump system and would like to get a nest thermostat.  On my system I have to switch it from heat to cold.  See picture of wiring.  If a nest won’t work what WiFi enable one will work.[image]
[image]

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler/furnace please, as well as the wiring diagram for said indoor unit?

Comment: I didn’t see a diagram but hopefully these will help

Comment: Which version of the Nest are you interested in? Also, here's the [installation manual for your indoor unit](https://www.sidharvey.com/documents/UNI-03396_Instal.pdf)

Comment: Also, which terminals  on your thermostat do the red and green wires in the thermostat cable land on? I can't tell from your photo...

Comment: Green goes to G Red goes to R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Nests have no trouble with heat pumps

A simple, single-stage heat pump like yours shouldn't be an issue for a Nest, even the stripped down E model.  Your wiring goes as follows:

- Red to R or Rc
- Blue to C
- White to AUX if present, or W1 if not
- Yellow to Y1
- Green to G
- and Orange to O/B

Just remember to set your Nest up for a heat pump and set its O/B setting for an O wire if it isn't set that way already, and you should be good to go.